# Is that any way to use xdebug without compiling the source in linux?

Tags: php, linux, xdebug

i have to use a tool for mesuring the memory usage in a projet where the charge and the number of visitors is huge , also i don't have a direct access to the server; i can just configure some tricks using the webmin and make some move, copy and past for the files... so i'm asking isn't there a way to get the xdebug.so to make the debugging work without compilation !!

Comment: What are "internautes"?

Comment: why the votedown ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanna asnwer my question , for those who are in a similar situation here i find the precompiled files needed :
http://code.activestate.com/komodo/remotedebugging/

Comment: Thanks for link! If you get this error "wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64" choose de 32 bits file.